# How to make a table in Excel based on a text file?

Tags: excel, ms-office, version

I'm attempting to get data from a text file as a table in Excel. Here is the format of the data in the text file:

```
   Name:
Element:
Ability:
 WpnATK:
 WpnDEF:
 MagPOW:
 MagRES:
  Speed:
   Move:
   Jump:
  Evade:
   Desc:
 Effect:
```

I've got the names on the left and want all the other data as column headings. Does Excel have anything to accomplish this or am I stuck just typing all of it in?

Comment: the question is a bit vague with `all the other data has column headings` but look into (on the Ribbon) `Data > From Text` and / or `Data > Text to Columns`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can input "From text" files in the DATA ribbon.

There you can select how to deliminate the data into excel.

Then transpose or copy and paste the columns/rows until it is how you want it.